# Is casting Child to Parent fine?

Tags: java, android, casting, parent-child, instanceof

I have the following piece of code in my Android project:

```
// The OnTouchListener is used so we are able to trigger the OnItemClickListener of the ListView,
// even though an EditText or AutoCompleteTextView is focused
private OnTouchListener itemOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v instanceof EditText){
            EditText et = (EditText)v;
            et.setFocusable(true);
            et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
        else{
            MyHolder h = (MyHolder) v.getTag();
            h.etAmount.setFocusable(false);
            h.etAmount.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            h.actvName.setFocusable(false);
            h.actvName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

view can be:

- `EditText`
- `AutoCompleteTextView`
- a few other view-elements

I've debugged the code and since [AutoCompleteTextView's parent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is EditText, the code also goes inside this if.

So my question: Is it safe to use `EditText et = (EditText)v;` on an AutoCompleteTextView to set its `setFocusable` and `setFocusableInTouchMode`? Or should I change it to the following instead?

```
// The OnTouchListener is used so we are able to trigger the OnItemClickListener of the ListView,
// even though an EditText or AutoCompleteTextView is focused
private OnTouchListener itemOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // WARNING: Leave this if above the if else for EditText,
        // since AutoCompleteTextView has EditText as parent
        if(v instanceof AutoCompleteTextView){
            AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)v;
            actv.setFocusable(true);
            actv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
        else if(v instanceof EditText){
            EditText et = (EditText)v;
            et.setFocusable(true);
            et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
        else{
            MyHolder h = (MyHolder) v.getTag();
            h.etAmount.setFocusable(false);
            h.etAmount.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            h.actvName.setFocusable(false);
            h.actvName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's fine as it is. That's what polymorphism is there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can cast  Child to a Parent since every Child is Parent. That's the beauty of OOP.

Comment: Ok, I thought so, but wasn't sure. Thanks. I will accept the answer in 10 min, since I can't yet after just creating the question. ;) Looks like my problem of my AutoCompleteTextView currently being unfocussable lies somewhere else, so I will look into this and perhaps create a new question if necessary.